# Time format (hh:mm a) not working for iOS 11.1.1 in swift 4

Tags: ios, datepicker, swift4, dateformatter

I am converting a time in format (hh:mm a). It is working fine for all other versions but it is giving error for 11.1.1

When I change current DateFormatter to time it gives hh:mm only

```
let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"

// Set date format
// dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
// Apply date format
let selectedtime: String = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
self.timeTextField.text = selectedtime

//// It gives 02:57 only What is missing although it is working for all other version.
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I faced the same issue on iOS **11.0.3**. 
My time format "h:mm a" or "hh:mm a" worked absolutely like "hh:mm", i.e. "21:00" was displayed instead of "9:00 PM" or "09:00 PM".

How to solve this:

1. If "21:00 PM" format is allowable, you can capitalize hours identifier "h" in your date format string, and "H:mm a" or "HH:mm a" formats will work!
2. But if not, set "locale" property of your dateFormatter. In my case it was  `dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];`

**Swift solution:** `dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")`
And I got "9:00 pm" string instead of wrong "21:00" after that.

OR

```
 dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.system
```